# using a graphml file for d3.js force-directed layout

Tags: xml, json, d3.js, graphml, force-layout

How do I use a graphml file with d3.js ? [i would like to draw a force-directed graph]

- is it simpler to convert the file to .json ? How ? I haven't been able to find a converter (I have found a python converter, but I'm not a python user)
- is it possible to directly use the graphml file ? may be with d3.xml ?

Note :
The graphml looks like this

```
<graph id="G" edgedefault="directed">
<node id="n0">
  <data key="v_name">JohnMaynardKe...</data>
  <data key="v_label">John Maynard Ke...</data>
  <data key="v_size">4</data>
  <data key="v_label.cex">0.3</data>
  <data key="v_frame.color">#ffffff00</data>
  <data key="v_color">#54FF00CC</data>
</node>
<node id="n1">
  <data key="v_name">JosephA.Schum...</data>
  <data key="v_label">Joseph A. Schum...</data>
  <data key="v_size">4</data>
  <data key="v_label.cex">0.3</data>
  <data key="v_frame.color">#ffffff00</data>
  <data key="v_color">#54FF00CC</data>
</node>
<edge source="n0" target="n1">
  <data key="e_nombre">2</data>
  <data key="e_width">2</data>
  <data key="e_arrow.size">0</data>
  <data key="e_color">#00000021</data>
</edge>
<edge source="n0" target="n7">
  <data key="e_nombre">2</data>
  <data key="e_width">2</data>
  <data key="e_arrow.size">0</data>
  <data key="e_color">#00000021</data>
</edge>
```

....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will recommend that you convert your graphml file in a json file. I ran into the same issue and here's how I convert a graphml file in json using python and the networkx library:

```
import networkx as nx
import json
from networkx.readwrite import json_graph
import re

G=nx.read_graphml('YourFile.graphml', unicode)
data = json_graph.node_link_data(G)

for node in data['nodes']:
  str=node['id']
  node['id']=[int(s) for s in str.split("n") if s.isdigit()][0]

with open('YourFile.json', 'w') as f:
  json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

The for loop in the code converts your node ids into numbers. This is very important since the sources and target in the json final file are already numbers (not characters).

Answer (score 3):

Following on from @fccoelho, [Anders Eriksen (anderser)](https://github.com/anderser) has put together an example of **converting [GraphML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphML) XML to [d3 JSON format](https://www.dashingd3js.com/data-structures-d3js-accepts) with Python, [here](https://gist.github.com/anderser/7432419)** ([GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/anderser/7432419))

[convert.py](https://gist.github.com/anderser/7432419) <- GraphML-to-d3_JSON

The Python script takes advantage of the [Python-louvain](https://bitbucket.org/taynaud/python-louvain) and [Networkx.github.io](http://networkx.github.io) libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Using Python and networkX you can read the graphml: http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.graphml.read_graphml.html

and then save in as JSON in a variety of flavors:
http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/readwrite.json_graph.html

Answer (score -1):

OK, I have finally found some way to convert a graph into d3.js-compliant .json
http://coulmont.com/blog/2012/11/03/reseau-d3js/
That's done with R and the RJSONIO library (annotations are in French)

```
library(RJSONIO) 
#creation de la partie qui renseigne les "nodes"
temp<-cbind(V(g2)$name,V(g2)$group)
colnames(temp)<-c("name","group")
js1<-toJSON(temp)
#creation de la partie qui renseigne les "liens"
write.graph(g2,"Desktop/edgelist.csv",format="edgelist")
edges<-read.csv("Desktop/edgelist.csv",sep=" ",header=F)
colnames(edges)<-c("source","target")
edges<-as.matrix(edges)
js2<-toJSON(edges)
#concatenation des deux parties
reseau<-paste('{"nodes":',js1,',"links":',js2,'}',sep="")
write(reseau,file="Desktop/reseau.json")
```

Comment: Try clickme, an R package to generate JS visualizations with R input data http://bit.ly/rclickme